# NodeJs module.exports, one function calls other. Other is not defined

Tags: node.js, module, puppeteer, module.exports

i tried a lot of suggested fixes that has been posted here before but i dont really know what else i can do.

[image: Here is project structure]

In scrapers i have 3 function. One main and two helpers. I import to index.js in routes.

```
const { scrape, scrapeChannel, iterateProducts } = require('../../services/scrapers.js');
```

Then i call scrapeChannel('url') but im keep geting scrape is not defined. When i console.log(scrape) it shows that it exist in index.js

scrapers.js all function are exported this way

```
module.exports.iterateProducts = function()  {logic}
```

Here is how whole import looks like
[image: Import]

@Marc
index.js

```
   const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { scrape, scrapeChannel, iterateProducts } = require('../../services/scrapers.js');

let content = scrapeChannel('Placeholder cuz private, its working');
console.log(content)
router.get('/', async (req,res) => {   
    const creators = [
        {name: "Test test", img: 'https://'},
        {name: "bRAH BDSF", img: 'https://'},
        {name: "123 123", img: 'https://'},
    ]

    res.render('site/show')
})

router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('succes')
})


module.exports = router;
```

scrapers.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


module.exports.scrape = function () {
    let list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".selenium-price-normal"), e => e.innerText);
    let name = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(" div.product-header > h2 > a"), e => e.innerText);
    return [list, name];
}

module.exports.iterateProducts = function (productName, productPrice){
    let titles = [];
    let prices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < productName.length - 4; i++) {
        titles.push(productName[i]);
    }
    for (let y = 1; y < productPrice.length - 3; y = y + 2) {
        prices.push(productPrice[y].split(',')[0].replace(/\D/g,''))
    }
    let result = Object.fromEntries(titles.map((_, i) => [ titles[i], prices[i]]));
    result = Object.entries(result)
    console.log(result)
    return result
}

module.exports.scrapeChannel = async function (url) {
    console.log(scrape)
    let allProducts = [];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(90000);
    await page.addStyleTag({ content: "{scroll-behavior: auto !important;}" });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(url);
    while (await page.$("#product-list > div.paging > a.paging-next.selenium-WC-paging-next-button")) {
    await page.evaluate(scrape).then(async el => {
        try {
                if (await page.$('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')) {
                    await page.click('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
                    await page.waitFor(1500)
                }
                let products = await iterateProducts(el[1], el[0])
                allProducts = products.concat(allProducts)
                await page.waitFor(1000)
                await page.click('#product-list > div.paging > a.paging-next.selenium-WC-paging-next-button')
                await page.waitForNavigation();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('errrrr!!!!!!!!!!', error)
        }
    })}
    allProducts = allProducts.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
    return allProducts
}
```

Comment: @Marc Main post has been updated

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because, at the moment of declaring `scrapeChannel`, `scrape` is not defined. So, when you call `scrapeChannel`, `scrape` is still not defined inside the function closure. You can read more about javascript closures here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

You shouldn't be relying on variables declared on other files without importing them.

If you want to reference the `scrape` function inside `scrapeChannel`, I would recommend either one of this options:

```js
const scrape = module.exports.scrape = () => {}
module.exports.scrapeChannel = () => {scrape();}
```

```
module.exports.scrape = () => {}
module.exports.scrapeChannel = () => {module.exports.scrape();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `this` to `scrape` and `iterateProducts` fixed the problem. But still if someone can  explain why `this` is needed

```
await page.evaluate(this.scrape)
let products = await this.iterateProducts(el[1], el[0])
```

Comment: Probably because `module.exports` is an object, so you're trying to access another property on the object from a function attached to that object. Without `this`, you're probably asking for a global `scrape`. With `this`, you're asking for a property on `module.exports`. You can (should!) strip your code down to a simpler example that communicates the same fundamental behavior: `module.exports = {foo: function () {}, bar: function () {console.log(/*this.*/foo)}}`.